# VSCode: coverage run results in ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I have a project in vscode with the following structure:

```
project_root/
    src/
        __init__.py
        b.py
        a.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        test_a.py
    .vscode/
        launch.json
        settings.json
    .env
    __init__.py
```

My settings for the unittests are:

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./tests",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
```

and in `.env` I have set:

```
PYTHONPATH=${WORKSPACE_FOLDER}${pathSeparator}src
```

Here `test_a.py` calls a function in `a.py` while `a.py` imports a class inside `b.py`.
At the beginning, I was not able to run `test_a.py` and got the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
```

But after adding `"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"` into `settings.json` and  additionally creating `.env` and adding `PYTHONPATH=${WORKSPACE_FOLDER}${pathSeparator}src` into `.env`, I was able to run the tests in vscode using the Testing panel on the left side of vscode.

But when I try to run the `coverage` command in the vscode terminal:
`coverage run --source=./tests,./src,./src/model_manager -m unittest` I get again the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
```

I also tried `python -m coverage run --source=./tests,./src,./src/model_manager -m unittest` but I am receiving the same error message.

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

**PS:** I am not able to change the PATH and environment variables for the whole user account as I don't have the permissions for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
```

This works in debug mode or interactive window.

You can use F5 or right click then choose **Run in interactive window**:

[image]